# pyaudio - mic settings don't match

Tags: pyaudio

Hi all[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtTEH.png)

I have a new mic for my pc, this mic can take an audio sample in many formats (I added pic below).
when I use "pyaudio.get_default_input_device_info()" , I get the Mic name but I don't see the sample rate as I defined it on the windows settings.
as you can see, although the currently mic settings are:
1 channel, 24bit, 88200Hz.
there is no device in the list that matches those settings.
my goal is to get the active mic: sample rate, channels, sample width (in bytes).

many thanks

```
def main():

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    input_mic = p.get_default_input_device_info()
    print("default input device: ")
    print(input_mic)
```

```
default input device: 
{'index': 1, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'Microphone (Speedlink Audis Pro', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 1, 'maxOutputChannels': 0, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.09, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.09, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.18, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.18, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
```

I try to get the current active mic settings: sample rate, channels, sample width (in bytes).